# Hide Joomla slideshow module on user memberpage does not work

Tags: templates

I installed a template (Purity III) and configured the slideshow module that came with the template (I use Joomla v3). I want to have this module shown only on the public pages, not when the user has logged in.

Therefore, within the Module Manager after selecting the slideshow module I:

- Set 'Access' to 'Public' within the Module tab.
- Set 'Module assignment' to 'Only pages selected' within Menu assignment; the menu selection then refers to the main menu

But when I log in as a user the slideshow module still appears(?). What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Setting the module access level to Public means that guests will be able to view it along with all child groups. In other words, everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Change the access level to **guest** instead of **public**.

As told in the comments, public means everyone is registered or not registered.

[Here are the instructions on how to set this up](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_hide_something_from_logged_in_users?)

Answer (score 0):

If I have a clear view of your question, Joomla 3 provides by default the guest group and guest access level intended for this exactly purpose.

By default, the public view gives view access to all the default usergroups, except from the Guest usergroup. Therefore any user of the registered and higher usergroup will always have viewing accesss to any content/item/module of that level.

So, if you want to display something only to visitors that are not logged in, you need to use an access level that these usergroups don't have.

This is the Guest Access Level and it is only assigned to the Guest usergroup, where none of your registered users will belong.

Finally, you want to make sure that you have the right option selected in the users component configuration, for the default Guest User Group. Click on the Options button of the com_users and check the Guest User Group selection to be "Guest".